# Swift and JSON UUID - Write to var and read from the var the id's are different

Tags: json, swift, uuid

I did wrote some code to save some struct to disk in JSON format.
However, if I save it in a variable and keep that and use it to decoded it then the UUID's are different.

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport
import Swift

struct Project: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable  {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let id2: String = UUID().uuidString 
    let name: String
}

let project = Project(name: "PP50")
let encodedData = try JSONEncoder().encode(project)
let jsonString = String(data: encodedData,
                        encoding: .utf8)

print(project.id)
print(project.id2)
print(project.name)
print(jsonString)
print("===================")

if let dataFromJsonString = jsonString?.data(using: .utf8) {
    let projectFromData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Project.self, from: dataFromJsonString)
    print(projectFromData)
    print(projectFromData.name)
    print(projectFromData.id) // <<< why is the id and id'2 different
    print(projectFromData.id2)
}
```

The result is:

```
826FEC8A-7FE0-4E6C-8DC1-A0DFA4FC75BE
2D15A1B8-B936-4829-8DC2-9C44B261712E
PP50
Optional("{\"id\":\"826FEC8A-7FE0-4E6C-8DC1-A0DFA4FC75BE\",\"id2\":\"2D15A1B8-B936-4829-8DC2-9C44B261712E\",\"name\":\"PP50\"}")
===================
Project(id: E951D459-3C0E-43A3-B9C6-2CCF2EB1AEE3, id2: "3C97B5C3-054D-4372-800D-9210439F48C2", name: "PP50")
PP50
E951D459-3C0E-43A3-B9C6-2CCF2EB1AEE3
3C97B5C3-054D-4372-800D-9210439F48C2
```

Maybe a simple answer, but I don't see it yet.
Why is the outcome of the id different then the one created?
How come? How to solve this?

Comment: when you have a `let` such as `let id: UUID = UUID()`, the compiler tells you that the property
 will not be decoded because it is declared with an initial value. That means
 the `id` (and id2) will be `generated` every time you create a new `Project`. That is why you get a different id.

Comment: Of course - I understand it. Thank you for explaining 'the why'; I appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to `var` declare your `id` properties and they will be included in the decoding

```
var id: UUID = UUID()
var id2: String = UUID().uuidString
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said in comments and other answers, `let` properties declared with initial values are not decoded and the default value will be used. In this case, the default is a new UUID.

Changing the properties to `var` will include them in decoding, even with the default values. However, since identifiers probably shouldn’t be mutable, an implementation which keeps the properties as `let` but has the same externally visible API is to use an explicit initialiser to provide the default values:

```
struct Project: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable  {
    let id: UUID
    let id2: String
    let name: String
    
    init(name: String, id: UUID = UUID(), id2: UUID = UUID()) {
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.id2 = id2.uuidString
    }
}
```

By providing default values in the initialiser, a `Project` can still be created with just a name. Since the properties themselves do not have an initialiser, they will be decoded.

Comment: Yes this is safer and a good implementation but it doesn't really answer the question of why OP got different id values before and after decoding.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - True, but now I know also why other code did work before when I did use almost the same code as shown compared with my test code above.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, that’s a very good point. I have reworded my answer to include the reason why the properties are not decoded.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an instance of `Project`, `id` and `id2` are constants that get default values from `UUID()` - you can't modify these values when decoding a JSON.

`id` and `id2` need to be variables (`var`), not constants (`let`). By doing this, the values can be modified by the JSON contents.